# Java jar in HTML?

Tags: java, japplet

I tryed using a Java Applet, but I didn't work, I supposed that it wasn't working because it required some files and libraries that weren't inside the .jar but outside in the same folder. So I looked for web pages that used Java Applet to put a .jar into HTML5, and they don't work.

How can I put a .jar file (that uses Canvas) into HTML5?

Thanks!

Roger

Comment: Most modern browsers stopped supporting java applets a while ago.. time to switch to HTML5 and JavaScript.

Comment: Java applets are an obsolete technology, which is becoming less and less possible to use. The most recent version of Firefox blocked it completely, and Chrome blocked it even before that. If you want active objects in a web page, use what @tkausl recommended. If you want to launch a Java application from a web site without embedding it, you can use Java Web Start.

Comment: “I[t] didn't work, I supposed that it wasn't working because it required some files and libraries that weren't inside the .jar but outside in the same folder.” Don’t guess; look at the errors and pay attention to them.  If you’re getting an exception, edit your question and add the *entire stack trace* of the exception to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
  <param name="code" value="Sample" />
  <param name="archive" value="Sample.jar" />
  Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
```

This is an example to do this

You still can use applets in firefox 32-bit and explorer for example